# Aplicar .map() pero a un rango de elementos especificos de un array

Tags: javascript

tengo una duda. Supongamos que yo tengo un array de elementos por ejemplo este:

```
const array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

Se puede aplicar la funcion .map() pero a un rango especifico de este array? por ejemplo desde el [0] al [6] ?

Comment: ¿Se debería de modificar el arreglo original? [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) no lo hace, por eso pregunto

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes probar con el metodo `slice` en el arreglo.

El metodo `slice` se encarga de cortar el arreglo, tendremos que pasarle como parametros los indice de inicio y final.

```js
const array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

array.slice(0, 6).map(n => console.log(n))
```

Answer (score 1):

No se puede hacer directamente.

Lo más óptimo que puedes hacer es crear tu propia función `map` con lo que necesitas.

Un ejemplo:

```js
function map(arr, fun, beg = 0, end = 0){
    if (end <= 0)
        end = arr.length

    let newArr = []
        
    for (let i = beg; i < end; i++){
        newArr.push(fun(arr[i]))
    }

    return newArr
}

let test = [1, 2, 3, 9, 8, 7]
console.log(map(test, e => e + 10, 2, 6))
```